# Count Distinct Values Based on Certain Values on Certain Column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, unique-values

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

| name | category | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | student | yes |
| Jane | employee | no |
| Elijah | student | no |
| Anne | student | yes |
| Elle | employee | no |

I want to count the number of each categories that have status 'yes'

I have tried 2 codes below:

1. `(DataFrame['status'].eq('yes').groupby(DataFrame['category']).nunique())`
2. `(DataFrame['status'].eq('yes').groupby(DataFrame['category']).any().sum())`

both codes give the same output:

category

student   2

employee  1

but, this is the **output that I expect**:

category

student   2

employee  0

can you help me fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If need count `True`s values need aggregate `sum`, because `True`s are processing like `1` and `False` like `0`:

```
s = (DataFrame['status'].eq('yes').groupby(DataFrame['category']).sum())
print (s)
category
employee    0
student     2
Name: status, dtype: int64
```

If aggregate `nunique` get count of unique values in first `True, False` return `2` and in second `No` return `1` (no `Yes` for second group).

For testing check unique values per groups:

```
print ((DataFrame['status'].eq('yes').groupby(DataFrame['category']).unique()))
category
employee          [False]
student     [True, False]
Name: status, dtype: object
```

If use `any` it test if at least one `True` per groups, so ouput is different:

```
print ((DataFrame['status'].eq('yes').groupby(DataFrame['category']).any()))
category
employee    False
student      True
Name: status, dtype: bool
```

Comment: [read pandas DataFrame any() her ](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html)